# Qt5: drawing on X11 root screen (and changing the WId of an existing QWidget

Tags: qt5, x11, desktop

Is it still possible in Qt5 to draw on the X11 root window and if so, how? As far as I understand this worked in Qt4 by changing the WId of an existing (just created) QWidget:

```
class Foo : public QWidget;

Foo:Foo(WId id)
        : QWidget()
{
    if (id) {
        create( id, false, true );
    }
}
```

Apparently this is no longer possible despite what looks like only minor changes to the underlying code.

The sanctioned replacement approach of using

```
QWidget::fromWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(QX11Info::appScreen()))
```

does not work for me: I get 2 more or less standard windows plus error messages:

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 850, resource id: 37748756, major code: 7 (ReparentWindow), minor code: 0
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 962, resource id: 37748760, major code: 7 (ReparentWindow), minor code: 0
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

I'm not calling paintEngine myself, and am also not doing any painting outside of my QWidget::paintEvent() override.

I see similar questions have been asked but remained unanswered, I hope this one has more success.

Answer (score 1):

appScreen returns a screen number, not a window ID. It returns 0 for the first screen/monitor, and that happens to the be default to tell QWidget() to create a new window. You need the QX11Info::appRootWindow() function.

Comment: Doh, yes. I'll need to check if indeed I use appScreen() directly (and this was NOT just an oversight when asking my question) or if I feed it into a function to obtain the corresponding root window ID.
Edit: I did however try with the QDesktopSomething class function that is supposed to return a QWidget corresponding to the root window, and that  gave me more or less the same results).